# Why didn't the Countermeasure nullify the Hammer of Dawn Satellite Array?

Tags: gears-of-war-series

This question actually stems from Gears 4 onwards...

When Adam Fenix fired the Countermeasure to end the Locust War, it completely destroyed the Lambent, as well as putting the Locust into a state of deep sleep (almost like hibernation).

IIRC, the Hammer of Dawn is an Imulsion based laser weapon, with Imulsion used as the primary source for it's offensive capabilities.

Building on this, since the Countermeasure destroyed all Imulsion on Sera, why didn't it nullify the Hammer of Dawn Network by destroying the Imulsion held in the Satellite's reserves?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Imulsion Countermeasure Weapon](https://gearsofwar.fandom.com/wiki/Imulsion_Countermeasure_Weapon) was created to destroy lambent cells using targeted radiation.

The Wiki linked above states the weapon's range as:

> Range: Planet-Wide

The weapon uses targeted radiation, and as our planet's atmosphere blocks out harmful radiation from space, its possible that [Sera's](https://gearsofwar.fandom.com/wiki/Sera) atmosphere is very similar, and could act as a barrier for the weapon, confining its effective area to just the planet, not the satellites orbiting.

Gears 5 minor spoilers (from Act 1):

> As for how it did not destroy the imulsion in the satellite you launch in the first Act of Gears 5, the satellite you find in [the old research facility](https://gearsofwar.fandom.com/wiki/Abandoned_Research_Facility) is a prototype, one that was created before the main imulsion powered satellites the player can use in Gears 1. Thus it could have been created with an impure imulsion power source. It still functions as we see later, but quickly loses connection.

Comment: Apologies for the late reply, but that does make sense. I really didn't think of Sera's atmosphere acting as a barrier here. As for the Gears 5 spoiler, I figured that the Hammer you launch is another variant of the HoD satellite system (i.e. like a nuclear powered variant). Marked as answer!